# How to mock class attribute instantiated in __init__?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm trying to mock the "self.api.friends.get" method in VKAuth class:

```
import vk

class VKAuth(object):
    def __init__(self, access_token, user):
        self.session = vk.Session(access_token = access_token)
        self.api = vk.API(self.session)

    def follow(self):
        vk_friends = self.api.friends.get()
```

from the test module test_views.py:

```
from mock import patch
from ..auth_backends.vk_backend import VKAuth

class AddUsersToList(TestCase):
    def test_auth_vk(self, mock_get):
         ... etc ...
        auth_token = 'ceeecdfe0eb4bf68ceeecdfe0eb4bf68ceeecdfe0eb4bf68652530774ced6cbc8cba0'
        token = user.auth_token.key
        self.client.defaults['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'Token {}'.format(token)
        with patch.object(accounts.auth_backends.vk_backend.VKAuth, 'api'): #point where we're mocking
            response = self.client.post(reverse('auth-social', kwargs=dict(backend='vk')), dict(access_token=auth_token), follow=True)
```

having created instance of VKAuth class during the post call to 'auth-social' above in SNView class-based view:

```
class SNView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.AuthSocialSerializer
    permission_classes = (rest_permissions.IsAuthenticated)

    def post(self, request, backend, *args, **kwargs):
        s = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA)

        if s.is_valid():
            auth_backends = {
                'vk': VKAuth,
                'facebook': FBAuth
            }

            if backend in auth_backends:
                auth_backend = auth_backends[backend](access_token=s.data['access_token'], user=self.request.user)
```

And I get an error:

```
AttributeError: <class 'accounts.auth_backends.vk_backend.VKAuth' doens't have the attribute 'api'
```

**What should I write istead of the current patch.object to reach api.friends.get and mock it?**

**UPD:**

To be more precise, I want some equivalent of:

```
    auth_token = 'ceeecdfe0eb4bf68ceeecdfe0eb4bf68ceeecdfe0eb4bf68652530774ced6cbc8cba0'
    user = User.objects.get(id = 2)
    vk_auth = VKAuth(auth_token, user)

    vk_ids=[111111,2222222,3333333,44444444]
    vk_auth.authenticate()
    vk_auth.api.friends = MagicMock(name='get', return_value=None)
    vk_auth.api.friends.get = MagicMock(name='get', return_value=vk_ids)
    data = vk_auth.follow()
```

but mock it the moment before we make request to the django-rest-framework api via self.client.post().

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are patching the wrong thing. In `VKAuth`:

```
self.api = vk.API(self.session)
```

add `api` attribute to `VKAuth` `self` **object**. When you call

```
patch.object(accounts.auth_backends.vk_backend.VKAuth, 'api')
```

you are patching the `api` static attribute of `VKAuth` class and not the object attribute.

You should patch `vk.API` instead.

```
with patch('vk.API', autospec=True) as mock_api:
    response = self.client.post(reverse('auth-social', kwargs=dict(backend='vk')), dict(access_token=auth_token), follow=True)
```

Notes :

1. Use [`patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) only if you really know why you need it instead simple `patch`.
2. `autospec=True` is not mandatory but [I strongly encourage to use it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing).
3. In the `patch` context `self.api` will be equal to `mock_api.return_value` because call `vk.API(self.session)` is like call `mock_api()`; in other words `mock_api` is the mock object used to replace the `vk.API` reference.
4. Take a look to [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch), you can find it very useful.

Now if you want fill your `mock_api.return_value` by some behavior you can configure it in `with` context:

```
with patch('vk.API', autospec=True) as mock_api:
    m_api = mock_api.return_value
    m_api.friends.return_value = None
    m_api.friends.get.return_value = vk_ids
    .... Your test
```

Comment: In my case it returns: AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'friends'

Comment: Remove autospec=true

Comment: Inside of the vk.API I see:

class API(object):
...
    def __getattr__(self, method_name):
        return Request(self, method_name)

class Request(object):
    __slots__ = ('_api', '_method_name', '_method_args')

    def __init__(self, api, method_name):
        self._api = api
        self._method_name = method_name

    def __getattr__(self, method_name):
        return Request(self._api, self._method_name + '.' + method_name)

    def __call__(self, **method_args):
        self._method_args = method_args
        return self._api._session.make_request(self)

Comment: As I removed autospec=True from patch, it outputs:
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pavel/api/accounts/tests/test_views.py", line 266, in test_auth_vk
    response = self.client.post(reverse('auth-social', kwargs=dict(backend='vk')), dict(access_token=auth_token), follow=True)

Comment: I cannot help you now. I will come back to it later

Comment: It seems as a possible reason:

class VKAuth(object):
    def __init__(self, access_token, user):
        self.session = vk.Session(access_token=access_token)
        self.api = vk.API(self.session)
        ...

    def authenticate(self):
        try:
            vk_uid = self.api.users.get()[0]['uid']

In other words, we've mocked everything in vk.API including api.users.get what we use for authentication.

Comment: How to except self.api.users from mocking?

Comment: Sorry, I'm busy now. I can't follow you now.